# tocloft moving toc onto title page below abstract

Tags: table-of-contents, page-breaking, tocloft, abstract

I am using the `tocloft` package in order to reduce the space between the toc header and the table of contents itself. However, the package is causing the table of contents to move up onto the title page, just below the abstract. Is there a way of stopping this effect? Thank you.

```
\documentclass[pdftex,11pt,a4paper,notitlepage]{report}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\setlength\cftaftertoctitleskip{0pt}

\begin{document}

% Title
\title{Chaos}
\author{Thomas Hopkins \\ School of Physics, University of Southampton}
\date{6th January 2014}
\maketitle % Output Title
% End Title

% Begin Notes

\begin{abstract}
\noindent
 hello
\end{abstract}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Introduction}
hello   

\end{document}
```

Comment: In addition to @umz's answer, calling `\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}` inhibits the tricks the package is doing to chapter titles.

Answer (score 2):

Add `\clearpage` before `\tableofcontents`.

```
\documentclass[pdftex,11pt,a4paper,notitlepage]{report}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\setlength\cftaftertoctitleskip{0pt}

\begin{document}

% Title
\title{Chaos}
\author{Thomas Hopkins \\ School of Physics, University of Southampton}
\date{6th January 2014}
\maketitle % Output Title
% End Title

% Begin Notes

\begin{abstract}
\noindent
 hello
\end{abstract}
\clearpage
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Introduction}
hello   

\end{document}
```

Now as written in the `tocloft` package:

> There is one difference between the standard LaTex behaviour and `tocloft` package. In the standard LATEX classes that have `\chapter` headings, the ToC, LoF and
>   LoT each appear on a new page. With the tocloft package they do not necessarily
>   start new pages; if you want them to be on new pages you may have to specically
>   issue an appropriate command beforehand.

This comes from `tocloft` package version number v2.3f section(2), last revised 2013/05/02.
Just to elaborate problem and solution here are two pictures:
[image]

This was before `\clearpage`. Now after `\clearpage` :[image]

Comment: Thank you, that worked well however it has thrown up another problem. I have removed the vertical space before chapter headings, but with using clearlastpage, the vertical space reappears for the contents header.

Comment: I have just put the picture of my solution. is it not what you wanted??Please, could you further elaborate the problem you are having. If this is not what you wanted, let me know and I will delete this answer.

Comment: No, this is exactly what I wanted, apart from now there is too much space above the Contents title on page 2.

Comment: You can change/adjust that space by adding \setlength{\cftbeforetoctitleskip}{-1in}                            in the preamble. 1in is the value which I have used just for example. You can change this as per your requirement. But remember in this case it must come with the negative '-' sign to reduce the space before table of contents title (as I have written it).